# Reading size of canvas error

Tags: c#, wpf

```
// Get the size of the canvas
Size size = new Size(surface.Width, surface.Height);
// Measure and arrange elements
surface.Measure(size);
surface.Arrange(new Rect(size));
```

For some reason this is returning an error reading:

```
UIElement.Measure(availableSize) cannot be called with NaN size.
```

Now what I'm doing is seeing if reading the StackPanel properties on the first page, and then when I load up on another page it will let me Edit it, but I get this error.

Comment: Nice. Now: What is the question?

Comment: @AttilaBujáki What in my code is creating this error?

Comment: The size contains NaN value. Thus it can't measure the size. Make sure that the passes surface.Wigth and surface.Height values are not NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `surface.ActualHeight` and `surface.ActualWidth` instead of `surface.Height` and `surface.Width`. The values are NaN currently.

Answer (score 1):

The size contains NaN value. Thus it can't measure the size. Make sure that the passes surface.Wigth and surface. Height values are not NaN.

Try using ActualHeight and ActualWidth properties of the Canvas, which are containing the actual height and width values of the Canvas.

Comment: Would i use it on the objects or the stackpanel?

Comment: On the surface, as you tried before. Based on what you wrote before you wanted to do that.

Answer (score 0):

availableSize can be any number from zero to infinite. Elements participating in layout should return the minimum Size they require for a given availableSize

```
/ Get the size of the canvas
Size size = new Size(surface.ActualWidth, surface.ActualHeight);
// Measure and arrange elements
surface.Measure(availableSize);
surface.Arrange(new Rect(availableSize));
```